# Single page of all html controls/tags to review style

Tags: html, css, tags

I remember a long time ago looking at what I thought was called a typography page to show all html tags that you can apply a style sheet to see how it will look on each control.

I can't seem to locate such a page online any longer.  I'm looking for a resource that list all tags, for example:

```
<h1>This is what an H1 tag will look like</h1>
<h2>This is what an H2 tag will look like</h2>
<h3>This is what an H3 tag will look like</h3>
...
<div>This is what a div tag will look like</div>
...
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, provide a resource, or correct me on my search terms?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML page with (most) all elements, for styling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790046/html-page-with-most-all-elements-for-styling)

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't have exactly what you're looking for there's W3schools references that are great that I frequently use and are similar to what you want. If you click on one of the tags it will give you examples what it will look like sometimes. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp for html and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp for css.